# How to Avoid Clearing Glide's Caches from Internal Storage?

Tags: android, caching, android-glide

I'm making an app that load abundant of images from internet, then store caches for offline use where Internet is not accessible. A lot of apps nowadays also loads images from Internet such as Instagram and Facebook but their caches not being removed/cleared after Internal caches is cleared.

How to avoid Glide's caches being cleared when performing Clear Cached Data in Internal Storage?

Answer (score 1):

Starting in Glide 3.5, you can use the `GlideModule` interface to lazily configure Glide and register components like `ModelLoaders` automatically when the first Glide request is made.

You can set the location of cache in public directory which will not be deleted:

```
package com.mypackage;

public class MyGlideModule implements GlideModule {
    @Override public void applyOptions(Context context, GlideBuilder builder) {
        builder.setDiskCache(
      new ExternalCacheDiskCacheFactory(context, cacheDirectoryName, yourSizeInBytes));
    }

    @Override public void registerComponents(Context context, Glide glide) {
        // register ModelLoaders here.
    }
}
```

look more at [wiki](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/wiki/Configuration#location).

Comment: where to add this method...? in the same line as Glide ? I've tried in the same line but it gave me errors.